# Esc to cancel drag event jquery drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag, onkeypress

I am using http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag

Sometimes user accidentally starts a drag or for any other reason wants to cancel drag, how can this be achieved?

A standard practice is that user can press esc.

How could we cancel drag with esc press using http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach event to the page to listen for <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and then manually trigger the `dragend` event.

```
var ESCAPE_KEYCODE = 27;
var dragEl = $('.draggable').drag(function( ev, dd ){
  // do stuff
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === ESCAPE_KEYCODE) {
         $(dragEl).trigger('dragend');
    }
});
```